# How to access to element data attribute after on click event inside javascript class object

Tags: javascript

I have a class in javascript that has a bindEvents() method to catch clicks events.
Every event fires a call to a new method of the same class.

I need some help to understand the `bind` and `this` effects.

```
class StdList {

constructor(config){
    this.config = config;

    this.api = 'api/v1/endpoint';

    this.bindEvents();
}

bindEvents() {

    this.config.container.on('click', '.do-edit', this.onEditClicked.bind(this) );
}

onEditClicked(e){

    var self = this;

    if (e)
        e.preventDefault();

    let row = $(this).data('item_id');

    console.log("onEditClicked row ID:", row); // onEditClicked row ID: undefined 
    console.log("Print API: ", self.api); // This works, and print api/v1/endpoint
}
```

}

The buttons .do-edit have a data attribute set like this `data-item_id="531"`.

If I do not use `bind(this)` I can easily access the button's attribute that has fired the event, with $(this).data(..), but I can't use other properties or methods of the class.
To use other class methods and properties I used the .bind(this) ... now I can access to the class but I can't access the button's attributes.

How can I get access to element properties and still have access to the class?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works. Don't know if it's the "best way" but it works.

I simply used the `event.target` function inside the onEditClicked method.

```
onEditClicked(e){

let row = $(e.target).data('item_id');

console.log("onEditClicked row ID:", row); // It works. onEditClicked row ID: 531 
console.log("Print API: ", this.api); // This works, and print api/v1/endpoint
```

}